# Generalization of Dirac delta identity

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, mathematical-physics, distribution-theory

The Dirac delta distribution obeys the following identity in $\mathbb{R}$

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\dfrac{1}{\pi}\dfrac{\epsilon}{\epsilon^2+x^2}=\delta(x)\tag1.$$

I know how to prove this using the Sokhotski–Plemelj theorem, namely $$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\dfrac{1}{x\pm i\epsilon}=\mp i\pi\delta(x)+{\cal P}\dfrac{1}{x},\tag2$$

where $\cal P$ means the principal value. Indeed subtracting the formula for the two signs it follows that

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\dfrac{1}{\pi}\left[\dfrac{\epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon^2}\right]=\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\left[\dfrac{1}{x-i\epsilon}-\dfrac{1}{x+i\epsilon}\right]=\delta(x)\tag{3}.$$

All that said, I'm interested in a generalization. I want to understand the small $\epsilon$ expansion of

$$\left(\dfrac{\epsilon}{\epsilon^2+\|x\|^2}\right)^a\tag{4}$$

where $a\in \mathbb{C}$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$. For example this often appears in some Physics papers when discussing the wave equation in hyperbolic spaces. It is often claimed that one has an expansion of the form $$\left(\dfrac{\epsilon}{\epsilon^2+\|x\|^2}\right)^a=\pi^{n/2}\dfrac{\Gamma\left(a-\frac{n}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(a)}\epsilon^{n-a}\delta^{(n)}(x)+\dfrac{\epsilon^a}{\|x\|^{2a}}+\cdots\tag{5}$$

where the dots denote subleading terms in the small $\epsilon$ expansion. Setting $a=1$ and $n=1$ and taking $\epsilon\to 0$ we recover (1). I would like to understand how to prove (5) and how to identify the order of the small $\epsilon$ corrections. I also want to understand whether some restriction on $a$ has to be made, another reason I want to fully understand the proof of this result. How can this be shown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For distribution theory proofs I always find it helpful to simply start by definition. Take test function $\phi\in C_0^\infty(\Bbb{R}^n)$ and consider

$$\tilde{f_\epsilon}(\phi)\equiv \widetilde{\left(\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon^2+x^2}\right)^a}(\phi) \equiv\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}\left(\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon^2+x^2}\right)^a\phi(x)\:dx$$

Simply put, the first non-delta contribution to the expansion can be found by considering $\phi$ with $0\notin\operatorname{Supp}\phi$

$$\tilde{f_\epsilon}(\phi) = \epsilon^a \int_{\Bbb{R}}\frac{1}{|x|^{2a}}\left(1-\frac{\epsilon^2}{x^2}+\cdots\right)^a\phi(x)\:dx \approx \widetilde{\left(\frac{\epsilon}{x^2}\right)^a}(\phi) + \widetilde{O\left(\left(\frac{\epsilon}{x^2}\right)^{a+2}\right)}(\phi)$$

as $\epsilon\to 0^+$. But now consider $\phi$ with $0\in\operatorname{Supp}\phi$ and use the substitution $x = \epsilon y$:

$$\tilde{f_\epsilon}(\phi) = \int_{\Bbb{R}^n}\left(\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon^2+\epsilon^2y^2}\right)^a\phi(\epsilon y)\:\epsilon^ndy = \epsilon^{n-a}\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}\frac{\phi(\epsilon y)}{(1+y^2)^a}dy $$

Then by dominated convergence take the limit of

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+} \epsilon^{a-n}\tilde{f_\epsilon}(\phi) = \int_{\Bbb{R}^n}\frac{\phi(0)}{(1+y^2)^a}dy = \operatorname{Area}\left(S^{n-1}\right)\cdot \int_0^\infty \frac{r^{n-1}}{(1+r^2)^a}dr \cdot \delta(\phi)$$

by converting to $n$-dimensional spherical coordinates. The constant out front can be computed to be the constant used in the approximation formula by plugging the appropriate formulas for the area of an $n-1$-sphere and the value of that integral into the above. More interestingly, we can answer your question about the restrictions on $a$. Namely, we have that

$$\operatorname{Re}\{a\} > \frac{n}{2}$$

by $p$-test. Therefore we have proven

$$\tilde{f_\epsilon}(\phi) \approx C(n,a)\delta(\phi) + \widetilde{\left(\frac{\epsilon}{x^2}\right)^a}(\phi) + \cdots$$

or less rigorously using the convention of representing deltas as functions we have

$$f_\epsilon(x) \approx C(n,a)\delta(x) + \left(\frac{\epsilon}{x^2}\right)^a + \cdots$$

A couple notes on notation:

I use $x^2$ to unambigiously mean the dot product $x\cdot x$ for $x\in\Bbb{R}^n$. But when appropriate, I do use single bars for the norm and reserved the use of double bars for norms on functions if any had appeared. Lastly, I'm not a fan of the physics notation $\delta^{(n)}(x)$ to mean the $n$-dimensional Dirac delta (I stared at this formula in confusion for quite some time because it looks exactly like the notation for the $n$th derivative of delta), so I simply write $\delta(x)$ to mean the unrigorous function representation of the more rigorously defined linear functional that performs $\delta(\phi) \equiv \phi(0)$ regardless of the dimension of the $0$. Most of these notational quirks are standard for mathematician-oriented texts on distribution theory.

Comment: Indeed, when reading the question, I thought it was the $n$th derivative of the Dirac delta.

Comment: Thanks @NinadMunshi, I understand now what's going on, and indeed it was the best idea to just go to the definition. There is just one thing that I'm a bit confused, which is in regards to the analysis in the case $0\notin{\rm supp}\phi$. In that case you just expand the integrand. Why that expansion only works for this case and misses the Dirac delta part? Is it related to the fact that the terms in the expansion diverge as $x\to 0$?

Comment: @Gold yes that is correct. It is understood that the domain of integration is really $\operatorname{Supp}\phi \subset\Bbb{R}^n$ so that expansion is only allowed if $0$ is not present.

Answer (score 3):

The OP question can be extended to much more general phenomenon.

Let $f$ be a continuous function absolutely integrable on $\mathbb{R}^n$ so that
$$\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)\,dx =1$$
Then $$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+} \varepsilon^{-n} f(\varepsilon^{-1}x)\to \delta(x)\quad (*)$$
In the OP example we have $n=1$ and $f(x)=\pi^{-1}(1+x^2)^{-1}.$

The equality $(*)$ means
$$\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} \varepsilon^{-n} f(\varepsilon^{-1}x)g(x)\,dx =g(0),\qquad g\in C_b(\mathbb{R}^n)\quad (**)$$ where $C_b(\mathbb{R}^n)$ denotes the set of all continuous bounded functions.
The proof of $(**)$ follows. $$\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} \varepsilon^{-n} f(\varepsilon^{-1}x)g(x)\,dx-g(0)\underset{x=\varepsilon y}{=} \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}  f(y)g(\varepsilon y)\,dy-g(0)\\
= \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}  f(y)[g(\varepsilon y)-g(0)]\,dy=\int\limits_{\|y\|\le N}  f(y)[g(\varepsilon y)-g(0)]\,dy+\int\limits_{\|y\|> N}  f(y)[g(\varepsilon y)-g(0)]\,dy$$ Next
$$\left |\int\limits_{\|y\|> N}  f(y)[g(\varepsilon y)-g(0)]\,dy\right |\le 2\max |g(x)|\int\limits_{\|y\|>N}|f(y)|\,dy$$
For given $\delta>0$ there is  $N$ so that $$2\max |g(x)|\int\limits_{\|y\|>N}|f(y)|\,dy<\delta$$ Next
$$\left | \int\limits_{\|y\|\le N}  f(y)[g(\varepsilon y)-g(0)]\,dy\right |\le \max_{\|u\|\le N\varepsilon}|g((u)-g(0)|\int\limits_{\|u\|>N}|f(u)\,du\le \max_{\|u\|\le N\varepsilon}|g((u)-g(0)|\,\|f\|_1
$$ By the continuity of $g$ at $0$ there is $\varepsilon_0>0$ such that $$ \max_{\|u\|\le N\varepsilon_0}|g((u)-g(0)|\,\|f\|_1<\delta$$ In particular for $0<\varepsilon\le \varepsilon_0$ we have
$$ \max_{\|u\|\le N\varepsilon}|g((u)-g(0)|<\delta$$ Summarizing the calculations we get
$$ \left |\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} \varepsilon^{-n} f(\varepsilon^{-1}x)g(x)\,dx-g(0)\right|<2\delta,\quad 0<\varepsilon\le \varepsilon_0$$

The example in OP is $$f(x)=c_a(1+\|x\|)^{-a}$$ where $c_a$ is the normalizing constant
so that the integral of $f$ is equal $1.$ The integrability assumption requires ${\rm Re}\,a>n/2.$